# Firebase Unity PC

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I am developing a PC game with unity and I want to use Firebase. After I downloaded the SDK and imported the packages, I got

[image]

Since the game is for PC only (not for iOS, Android or Web), I couldn't find where to download these files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase SDK for Unity allows you to build games that target Android and/or iOS devices. While it supports developing those games in a desktop, the Firebase SDK cannot currently be used to build games targeted for Desktops.

Comment: So is there a way to use Firebase for Desktops?

Comment: The Firebase SDK cannot currently be used to build games targeted for Desktops.

Answer (score 1):

**Firebase 4.5** includes *beta* support for a desktop workflow, but it's not intended for releasing desktop-targeted apps.

As stated in the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup):

> When you are creating an app, it's often much easier to test your app
>   in the Unity editor and on desktop platforms first, then deploy and
>   test on mobile devices later on in development. To support this
>   workflow, we provide a subset of the Firebase Unity SDK which can run
>   on Windows, OS X, Linux, and from within the Unity editor.
>
> > Authentication
> >     Realtime Database
> >     Remote Config
> >     Cloud Storage
>
> The remaining desktop libraries are stub (non-functional)
>   implementations, provided for convenience when building for Windows,
>   OS X, and Linux so that you don't need to conditionally compile code
>   when also targeting the desktop.

I've been able to utilize the `FirebaseDatabase` & `FirebaseStorage` packages for a desktop app, but positive results have been unreliable. The same code will work on one playthrough, then deadlock on another.  This could be due to a problem with my handling of `async`/`await` calls, or it could be the `FirebaseApp`, which throws [a cryptic '`false`' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701567/firebase-4-5-unity-false-error) outside of runtime.