# Checking whether Firebase is initialized successfully in Unity3D?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I've got a **Unity application** with **Firebase integration**, and I'd like to handle the case when I have to shut down the Firebase project for various reasons.

So the application will still function relatively normally, slightly differently.

I tried simulating this by **messing up** the `project_id` in the `google-services.json`.

But it didn't cause any errors, the firebase calls are just **aren't executed**.

Is there a way to check whether the **Firebase initialisation is successful or not?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, if you are using Firebase admin SDK on your app you can check it with:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase;

public class FirebaseController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public async Task InitializeFirebase()
    {
        await FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            if (task.Result == DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                Debug.Log("Firebase correctly Initialized");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + task.Result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this, and it still says that Firebase is correctly initialized. :\
It says it's correctly initialized, but none of the Firebase methods reach their callbacks, like this one: collection.AddAsync(documentData).ContinueWithOnMainThread(callback)

Comment: Didn't reach their callbacks, but It shows any message or error when calling firebase methods?

Comment: I tried logging in the first line of the callback, but it doesn't reach it. Is there some other way to find out?

Comment: I think it will only work in your build not editor.

Comment: @Tudvari did you try it on your build right? like Saad says

Comment: @SaadAnees I've just tried with a build, and it still runs into "Firebase correctly Initialized", but if I try to add a document, nothing happens.

Comment: And which message appears in your logcat?

Comment: @Lotan I've built it on Desktop, and it says "Firebase correctly Initialized", and logged everything until AddDocument, and also in AddDocument's callback. AddDocument is called, but it's callback is never called.

Comment: @Tudvari firebase Unity SDK only works on mobile plataforms, try It on a mobile device

Comment: @Lotan No, it works on Desktop. I've been using it for months. It works right now as well.  My problem is that I can't detect that it doesn't work.

Comment: @Tudvari You sure? Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49833317/firebase-unity-pc

Comment: @Lotan Well, it's a 2 years old post, and I don't know about official statements, but sure it's been working for half a year now on a daily basis. :\

Comment: @Tudvari https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup here you can see the official statement with the caution message about desktop support :(

Comment: @Lotan Well, if there's nothing else to be done... :\ Then thanks, at least I know now :)